# Testing Akka Typed actors - How can I get an ActorContext?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit, akka-typed, akka-actor

I'm trying to unit test a helper function of my actor.  This helper function spawns some actors and I want to assert that this happens.  In order to spawn them, the helper function needs the parent ActorContext, so that is passed in.  Example:

```
def getDefaultInitialState(context: ActorContext[Request]): State = {
  ...
  val actor1 = context.spawn(myChildActor(), name = f"MyChild1")
  ...
  State(actor1, ...)
}
```

So, now I'm trying to unit test this function.  In order to call it from my unit test, I need an ActorContext[Request].  I tried doing this in my test:

```
val testKit = BehaviorTestKit(MyParentActor()))
getDefaultInitialState(testKit.context())
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because the context() method of BehaviorTestKit is private.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [akka actor typed docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/testing-sync.html#spawning-children), you can also expect an effect in your test kit, which in your case, spawning an actor indeed is an effect. so I think this should probably help (abstraction of akka docs provided previously):

```scala
testKit.expectEffect(Spawned(myChildActor(), "myChild1"))
```

Alternatively, if your actors do not have a name, or you don't know the exact names, you can just expect anonymous actors only based on their behavior:

```scala
testKit.expectEffect(SpawnedAnonymous(myChildActor()))
```

Comment: Yes, I was planning to do something like that. However, that does not solve my original problem of how to get an ActorContext to pass in.  Without that, I can't even call my function under test in the first place.

Comment: Ok, can't you just pass the testKit into the method? I think it should work fine, you can easily spawn your actors into that and have control over it. And if you can't so, remember that actors are not there to instantiate, so everything including the ActorContext is private to the object, you cannot access it anywhere but inside the actor.

Comment: Passing the testKit into the method doesn't help because that still doesn't give me an ActorContext with which to spawn the child actors.  I'm not sure what you mean by "spawn your actors into that", but I'm testing production code, so it can't rely on a TestKit.  Yes, the ActorContext is private to the object, but I'm normally calling the helper function from inside the actor.  I just need to call the function from outside the actor in order to unit test it.

Comment: What I meant by  "spawn your actors into that" is that you can spawn actors inside the test kit context without explicitly passing the actor context. and also, I'm confused, you said you're testing production code and can't rely on a TestKit, but you also need the actor context of the test kit? anyway, knowing that ActorContext is private, the only solution would be to have a case class which extends `Request` which will basically invoke the function from inside the actor (I'm not a professional in actor model, but that's what I know, you just pass messages and actors are isolated)

Comment: Ok, it sounds like I may have resort to adding a new message that calls the function for the purposes of testing only, unless anyone else has any other solutions. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeMjr2 As far as I know yes :D. good luck!

Comment: It's worth noting that nearly all of the methods on an `ActorContext` will blow up if not used inside an actor (as in if they're called from a thread which is not processing a message for the actor associated with the context).

Comment: Im facing this very same issue; trying to test a child actor that is been spawn by a helper function from inside the parent actor